# Minecraft launcher could not connect to server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, networking, minecraft-launcher

[image: Minecraft Login Screenshot]

What do I do? I looked at a similar question to mine and there was an answer saying to make sure Java is allowed past the firewall. So I checked and it already is. I've tried uninstalling and installing both Minecraft and Java but nothing has changed. [This link](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/) says that all services are fine, so what's going on? I bought a 2nd account to use as an alternative in-game account and now I can't log in.

(I cleared the email and password boxes for obvious reasons in this screenshot: security purposes)

Comment: So can I get some help instead of being downvoted for no reason?

Comment: It sounds like something is blocking Minecraft - it could be your antivirus or parental control software. [#minecrafthelp (scroll down to Unofficial Help Resources)](https://minecraft.net/en-us/help/) should be able to assist.

Comment: That page showing the service statuses is not only unofficial, it also doesn't work anymore. Here's the proper link: https://help.mojang.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same thing happen to me on my laptop. Try rebooting the game and then your router.

Answer (score -1):

Try rebooting your wi-fi. If that does not work contact mojang at:
https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new?ref=footer

Thank you.

Comment: I already tried that, and I've looked mojangs support page, it doesn't mention anything about the launcher not connecting to the servers. I also contacted them on twitter and have had no responce.

Comment: Try contacting them via email:https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new?ref=footer